# i want checksum promng for these data " 1B 02 1D 01 01 0B 03'' I want these data a python software. output should be B0h

Tags: python, checksum

i want checksum programming in  python language. data is "1B 02 1D 01 01 0B 43 6F 64 50 61 64 20 54 65 78 74 1B 03  "  Output should be - B0h. ( ascii to hexadecimal convertion ) .

Comment: Please provide the code you worked on. You can refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . The more details you provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: _who_ says the answer should be 0xB0h? Ask them how and why. Need to know spec for what kind of checksum you're trying to calculate